# How to use apache-dolphinscheduler's queue?

Tags: apache-dolphinscheduler

I am confused about the apache-dolphinscheduler's queue, as in user-guide, the queue is used for spark、mapreduce. But I want to use python code product seeds to queue and another python code in workers pull seeds from queue and run tasks. Can you tell me whether dolphinscheduler can handle it or I must use another tools, such as Redis?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as what you said, you need to use another tools. the queue designed to choose corresponding queue which exists in hadoop yarn cluster.